# How to validate Exchange credentials and verify Exchange server communication using EWS managed API?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Using Exchange EWS managed API 2.0, here is a method which I'm using to validate credentials:

```
public static bool TestExchangeConnetion(UserSettingDTO credential, ServerSettingDTO serverSetting)
    {
        bool authenticated = false;
        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService service;


        service = new ExchangeService((ExchangeVersion)Enum.Parse(typeof(ExchangeVersion), serverSetting.ExchangeVer));
        service.Url = new Uri(serverSetting.ExchangeURL);


        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credential.ExchangeUsername, credential.ExchangePassword);

        try
        {
            //make a call to ensure that credentials are working
            AlternateIdBase response = service.ConvertId(new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, "Placeholder", credential.ExchangeUsername), IdFormat.EwsId);
        }
        // The credentials were authenticated. We expect this exception since we are providing intentional bad data for ConvertId
        catch (ServiceResponseException)
        {
            authenticated = true;
        }

        // The credentials were not authenticated.
        catch (ServiceRequestException)
        {
            authenticated = false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            authenticated = false;
        }

        return authenticated;
    }
```

This works absolutely fine to validate credentials but I'm looking for a way to differentiate between invalid credentials and Exchange server downtimes. This code returns false for both.
Is it possible to find out if there is an issue communicating to the server (like server downtimes)? The reason for this is I want to notify the user about invalid credentials not server downtimes!

Answer (score 3):

EWS is just a Web-service that runs on IIS (so IIS is looking after authentication) if you just want to check the credentials why don't you just make a Get request against the services.wsdl file or a Get on the Autodiscover endpoint on the CAS server. If the credentails are incorrect that should return a 401 at that point.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: The question is how would you differentiate between server downtime and invalid credentials? because using my code both returns not authorized.

Comment: If you getting a 401 then your credentials aren't any good, with credentials don't think in terms of Exchange you just authenticating. Define downtime ? if the CAS is down you won't get a response, if the Maillbox Server is down but the CAS is up you should get 500 error. If both servers are up but the store isn't mounted then you would get a specific EWS error. You need to really specific if its just credentials you can validate them outside of EWS.